# Checkbutton in tkinter is not storing values into variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I'm just doing my first steps in tkinter and I'm stuck trying to figure out why this code is not working:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
spam = StringVar()
checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(
    root, text="SPAM?", variable=spam, onvalue="Yes, SPAM!", offvalue="Boo, SPAM!")
checkbutton.pack()
print(spam.get())

root.mainloop()
```

The variable `spam` is empty, no matter if my `checkbutton` is checked or unchecked. Looking at the examples and documentation was a dead end too. Why is my variable still empty?

Comment: You are printing the value about a millisecond after you create the widget. The user will not even have seen the UI yet, much less interact with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
print(spam.get())
```

with:

```
checkbutton['command'] = lambda arg=spam: print(arg.get())
```

In order to see that the variable indeed does store the values.

---

The problem is when your `print` is called `spam.get()` equals `""` as:

```
spam = StringVar()
```

is identical to:

```
spam = StringVar(value="")
```

---

The `checkbutton` is initially on a default neither-on, nor-off state(as `spam` is neither the off nor the on value), but it's hard to notice for the [ttk](/questions/tagged/ttk) version(if at all), replace:

```
checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(...
```

with:

```
checkbutton = Checkbutton(...
```

to use the default Checkbutton from [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter), it is much more distinctively displayed.

Also further note that the `Checkbutton` requires being used in order to call `spam.set(checkbutton['onvalue'])` or `spam.set(checkbutton['offvalue'])`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help! That was exactly the problem.